# using regex expression to find a string within select tag html

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var mydata = null;
var par = [];
var job = [] ;
var customer = [];
var optionObject = {};
var table=document.getElementById('table2'),tr,input,row,cell

var selectPosition = $('#num1').val();
$.post('php/GetJobs.php',{'selectPosition': selectPosition }, function(data) {
    mydata = data;
    par = JSON.parse(mydata); 
    for (var i= 0; i <= par.length-1; i++) {
        job.push(par[i][0]);
        customer.push(par[i][1]);
        //optionObject["JobNum"] = job[i];
        // optionObject["Customer"] = customer[i];          
    }

    for (var row = 0; row <= 0; row++) {
        tr=document.createElement('tr');
        tr.setAttribute("class","rows");
        tr.id = "AddedRow";
        i++;

        for(var cell=0; cell<1; cell++){
            var field = document.createElement("select");
            field.setAttribute("id","jobSelector"); 

            var jobCol=document.createElement('td');
            jobCol.id = "row";

            for(var i =0; i <= job.length-1; i++){
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.setAttribute("value", "");
                option.text = job[i] + ' ' +  customer[i];
                field.appendChild(option);
                //var textNode = document.createTextNode();
                //jobCol.appendChild(textNode);
            }        

            //field.setAttribute("option","Select Job");
            /* We can run a for loop here to obtain all the options from php call*/

            **var projectCol =document.createElement('td');
            projectCol.setAttribute("class",'celltimes4');
            projectCol.id = "row";
            projectCol.appendChild(field);   
            tr.appendChild(projectCol); 
            var text = field.options[field.selectedIndex].text;
            var regex = new RegExp(text )
            var textNode = document.createTextNode(field.options[field.selectedIndex].text);
            jobCol.appendChild(textNode);

            tr.appendChild(jobCol);
        }**
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        for(var j =0; j <=6; j++){
            var field = document.createElement("input");
            field.setAttribute("class","alignRight");
            field.setAttribute("type","text");
            field.setAttribute("name","hours");
            field.setAttribute("value","");
            td=document.createElement('td');
            td.setAttribute("class",'celltimes4');
            td.id = "row" + i;
            td.appendChild(field);
            tr.appendChild(td); 
        }

        td=document.createElement('td');
        td.setAttribute("class",'celltimes4c');
        td.id = "row14total";

        tr.appendChild(td);
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
});
```

I know all this code was not necessary, but I been getting downvote because I don't provide the full working code even though it really won't work for any of you since I am doing PHP calls and JSON parsing.

However, my question lies in the bolded code. So what I am trying to achieve is take what is inside my select statement and only pull the job string and use that in the second second in the row. Right now how I have it, it takes the full value of the Select statement and places that inside my second cell.

So I am trying to use regexp to take the string out, but I simply can't figure out how to manipulate it.

Comment: What is the format of the `option` that you are trying to parse?  Your current code will just initialize a new `RegExp` object using the full text as the pattern (instead of the thing to search).

Comment: just fyi you have `for (var row = 0; row <= 0; row++) {...i++;`, `i` is not used in this scope

Comment: so this is my current code to extract the string out of the option value var text = field.options[field.selectedIndex].text;
     var regexp = new RegExp('((A-Z))','g');
     var result = text.match(regexp);
     var textNode = document.createTextNode(result);
     jobCol.appendChild(textNode);

Comment: (445930-1,2 Rivianna Foods) this is what is inside the option right now. So when the page loads, you will see this in the select along with bunch many more. So all i want is the string. I do not want the numerical values to the left.

Comment: You cannot just use `var regex = new RegExp(text);` as you need to escape regex metacharacters. See [`escapeRegExp` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: var regexp = new RegExp('([^0-9])','g'); so i am using this an I got the string out but before the word begins and between each letter, there are commas. How to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

You could use this regular expression to grab the text from the option: `[\d\-,]+\s+(.*)/`.

And here you have an example that stores in `textPart` the text portion of the option text.

```js
var text = "445930-1,2 Rivianna Foods";
var regex = /[\d\-,]+\s+(.*)/;
var textPart = text.match(regex)[1];
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = textPart;
```

```html
"445930-1,2 Rivianna Foods" extracted text to:
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: awesome it works!! Atleast one problem fixed. Maybe you can tell me why does my text inside my second cell not change when I change the option from cell 1? So what is happening is when I make a different selection from the options, my text inside my second cell does not change. Hints or tips?

Comment: If you want the content of your second cell to be updated everytime you change the selected option in cell 1 then you should add an onchange event handler on the dropdown to do that. ``` field.onchange =  function(){...}```
In case that's not the problem, then you should probably revise the regexp, to make it match the text on your cell 1; I created it based on the example you provided.